# How to store affected value after deleting parent

Tags: java, android, variables

I have two ArrayList variables
first
ArrayList listOrders;
the second is 
ArrayList selectedOrders = listOrders;

The problem is when i deleting listOrders it's clear selectedOrders value.
Is there a way to store value after deleting his parent?

Comment: It seams you are using two `ArrayList` but their reference is same. Please share the code where you are creating both list, deleting an item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hold 2 different references with the same data do:

```
ArrayList selectedOrders = new ArrayList<>(listOrders);
```

Comment: Thanks it's worked

Comment: I it works please mark the answer as accepted, thanks!

Comment: Do note that this is only creating a shallow copy.  If you modify elements contained in the "parent" list, they will affect the other list.